# ¿Como crear un período con php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

¡Hola buenas! , quisiera saber como podría crear periodos para diferentes años y que al seleccionar el usuario el periodo deseado me muestren los registros de ese año , no comprendo bien la lógica de como podría construirlo , cree una tabla years con los campos id,years , para guardar los años(periodos) para poder mostrarlo por un select , me produce el guardado y se me muestra en el select , pero quisiera saber que cuando seleccionas el nuevo periodo me muestren esos registros y que empieze nuevamente a contar el id a 1 por cada año , De antemano Me ayudarían Muchisimo! Aquí produje el Select de ejemplo :

```php
    $anio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'anio');

    $cons = "SELECT years FROM ano";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $cons);
```

```html
    <form class="container" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="POST">
      <select name="anio" id="anio" required>

        <?php while ($fila = $res->fetch_assoc()) {   ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $fila["years"] ?>">
            <?php echo $fila["years"] ?>
          </option>
        <?php   } ?>

      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

    </form>
```

(PD: Ya he hecho esta pregunta varias veces y me ayudaron muchas personas y les agradezco!,pero tal vez no lo he planteado muy bien la pregunta,espero que esta vez tenga bien planteado mi pregunta,de Antemano Muchas Gracias!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo una versión simplificada de lo que necesitas:

```
<?php

$txt=null;

$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');

if(isset($_POST['periodo'])){
    $rs=$conn->query("
        SELECT * FROM datos
          WHERE YEAR(fecha)=".($_POST['periodo']*1).";
    ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);    
    $txt.='<pre>'.print_r($rs,true).'</pre>';
}

$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(fecha) periodo
      FROM datos;
")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$txt.='<form method="post">'
    .'<select name="periodo">';
foreach($rs as $r)
    $txt.='<option>'.$r['periodo'].'</option>';
$txt.='</select>'
    .'<button>Ver</button>'
    .'</form>';

echo $txt;
```

Así como del dataset para que puedas probarlo:

```
CREATE TABLE datos(
  id_dato int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha date
  );
INSERT INTO datos (fecha) VALUES
  ('2021-11-01'),
  ('2021-12-01'),
  ('2022-01-01'),
  ('2022-02-01'),
  ('2022-03-01');
```

Es más o menos lo que has intentado hacer tú, así que no creo que necesites muchas explicaciones. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y te iré ampliando la respuesta con las aclaraciones que requieras.

Comment: Primero que nada , gracias por tu aporte David !! ,tengo una consulta, no es recomendable hacer cambios de tablas para poder mostrar los registros de el periodo escogido? me refiero a crear tablas con un boton de "crear periodo" y que este ejecute un script sql que tome como referencia el año local y concatenar ese año a la tabla para que cada tabla tenga un año de referencia,por ejemplo : salud2021,salud2022,salud2023 etc... Y ya de por si se produce una validacion ya que al concatenar la fecha local no va a crear la tabla con el mismo año de referencia.

Comment: Y en caso de que no fuera recomendable, que solución podría optar para mostrar la informacion del periodo escogido?me recomendaron particiones de tabla para producirlo , o un PA(Procedimiento Almacenado),me encantaria saber tu opinión, De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres con "crear tablas con un boton", pues las tablas las tienes en tu base de datos y los botones en la aplicación web que accede a esta base de datos: las tablas no tienen "botones". Particionar la tabla es una posibilidad, pero igual es matar moscas a cañonazos pues, con una simple selección con un `WHERE`, ya lo tendrías resuelto.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas se salen un poco de la temática de SO, que está orientado a dudas más concretas sobre el propio código. Te animo a contactar conmigo a través de LinkedIn y hablamos tranquilamente sobre lo que planteas, tienes el enlace en mi perfil de SO.

Comment: Claro!,Me encantaría , ya le envie una solicitud!

Comment: Aquí esta la pregunta un poco más completa de antemano Muchas Gracias ! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522962/como-guardar-registros-tomando-como-referencia-el-a%c3%b1o-en-una-tabla