# ¿Como concatenar la fecha local en el nombre de una tabla?

Tags: mysql

¡Hola!,quisiera saber si hay alguna forma que en mysql se pueda hacer esto ?

```sql
    SELECT * FROM ejemplo . date("Y")
```

Seleccionando la tabla ejemplo y concatenando el año local? sería asi ejemplo2022

Y con el ejemplo2022 seleccionar la tabla ejemplo 2022,no se si me explico!,De antemano Muchas Gracias!

(Editado)

Se que la sentencia esta incorrecta,me gustaria saber simplemente si es posible llamar a una tabla concatenando el año local a la cadena de texto "ejemplo" para buscar en la base de datos esa tabla , básicamente lo que intento lograr sería algo asi : `SELECT * FROM ejemplo2022` 
pero tomando como referencia el año local.

Comment: Explica mejor que buscas concatenar y como dejarlo. La primera consulta que pones no tiene sentido alguno y confunde.

Comment: @Excorpion Gracias por tu acotación ,lo editare enseguida!

Comment: Si necesitas tener tablas con nombres de fechas, por ejemplo por años, hay un error de diseño. Fragmentar innecesariamente los datos en una BD rompe la [regla del acceso garantizado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_reglas_de_Codd), es contraproducente para hacer búsquedas, actualizar registros, etc. De necesitar hacer divisiones en los datos, puedes intentar una [normalización](https://www.google.com/search?q=base+datos+normalizacion).

Comment: @aeportugal Gracias por tu aporte aeportugal! , exactamente hay un error de diseño , produzco esto porque no comprendo bien la lógica de como poder construir un filtrado por año con un select , y que me muestre los registros del año escogido por el cliente , por año , y que el id empiece nuevamente a 1 (porque es lo que me estan pidiendo) intente crear tablas concatenados con el año local para "resetear" nuevamente a 1 ya que es una tabla nueva, quisiera preguntar si hay un concepto que pueda explicar o identificar esta funcionalidad que intento hacer,de antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @aeportugal Y soy consciente de que lo que estoy indicando en el comentario , es diferente a la pregunta propuesta aqui , la pregunta que publique es una subpregunta para solucionar esta gran interrogante que se me presento, realmente el problema general es este : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/521179/como-crear-un-per%c3%adodo-con-php/521319?noredirect=1#comment925813_521319

Comment: A lo mejor con se puede hacer con un concat(ejemplo,year(now))

Comment: Esto solo puede resolverse mediante consultas dinámicas, es decir, construir la consulta concatenando la fecha al nombre de tabla en una variable y luego ejecutar una variable, esto es antinatural por muchas razones, pero hay situaciones en las que sería lógica emplear esta metodólogia. Revisa esto: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Pero, por cierto, como ya te han mencionado, sería mucho Mejor que `Ejemplo` tuviera una columna `Anio` e hicieras  `select * from Ejemplo where Anio=2022`