# ¿Como guardar registros tomando como referencia el año en una tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

¡Hola! , tengo un problema con la base de datos , estoy usando MySQL, y resulta que no comprendo la lógica de como poder guardar los registros de una tabla tomando como referencia el año creado, me recomendaron partición de tabla , ya que , necesito que los registros se guarden por el año de su creación y que el id del registro empiece nuevamente a 1 cuando empiece el nuevo año , **por ejemplo :** estamos en el año 2022 y hay 100 registros en la tabla "ejemplo" lo cual el id final es id 100, y cuando sea el año 2023 ese id empiece nuevamente a 1 ya que es el nuevo año , por eso he intentado crear tablas por ejemplo : "ejemplo2023",para hacer la diferenciación, y que claramente los registros del año 2022 no se pierda mas que al seleccionar el año 2022 se muestren nuevamente esos registros, si hay un concepto o funcionalidad que describe lo que intento hacer me ayudarían mucho!

**Código de ejemplo que he intentado hacer :**

Esto es en torno al select

```html
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {   ?>

                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $row["id"]  ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row["nombre"]  ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row["edad"]  ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row["fecha_registro"]  ?> </td>
                    <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Actualizar</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Eliminar</a> </td>

                </tr>
            <?php }  ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="POST">
        <select name="anio" id="anio">
            <?php while ($fila = $res->fetch_assoc()) {   ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $fila["years"] ?>"><?php echo $fila["years"] ?></option>
            <?php   } ?>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">


    </form>
    <a href="crearperiodo.php">Crear Periodo</a>
```

Aqui intento hacer el cambio de tablas con un switch ,para hacer el "reseteo", se que esto no es correcto y es un mal diseño pero me gustaría saber como solucionarlo.

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2023 ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$anio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'anio');
// if (date("Y") > $anio) {
//     //bloqueo CRUD
// }
$cons = "SELECT years FROM ano";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $cons);
if ($anio) {
    // echo 'SELECT * FROM  `example' . $anio . '`';

    // $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `example' . $anio . '`'); //  Select the example tableTable and concatenate the year that comes to me by post
    switch ($anio) {
        case "2022":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2022";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2023":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2023";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2024":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2024";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2025":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2025";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2026":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2026";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2027":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2027";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2028":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2028";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2029":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2029";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;
        case "2030":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM daem2030";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            break;

        default:
            echo "No se hallo nada";
    }


    echo $anio;
    // echo $anio;
} else {
    echo "No se muestra nada ";
}
```

Aquí lo que hago es crear tablas tomando como referencia el año local ,se que esto está mal y que a la larga es malo , pero por eso quisiera saber como solucionarlo, dé antemano Muchas Gracias!

```html
<?php
include "conexion.php";
// Por defecto, el año actual
$nuevoPeriodo = date("Y");

// Aquí insertas el nuevo periodo en la tabla
$sql = "INSERT INTO ano (years) VALUES($nuevoPeriodo)";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
//Valida nuevo periodo y se crean las tablas correspondientes a ese año

if ($res) {
    $db->query('CREATE TABLE `daem' . date('Y') . '`
(
id int(240) auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(40) null,edad varchar(40) null,fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT pk_daem PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

'); // create table
    $db->query('CREATE TABLE `salud' . date('Y') . '`
(
id int(240) auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(40) null,edad varchar(40) null,fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT pk_salud PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

'); // create table
    echo "Se produjo la insercion y creacion de periodo nuevo  " . date("Y");
} else {
    echo "No se produjo";
}

?>
<a href="index.php">Ir al inicio</a>
<?php
```

Comment: Da la sensación de que puedes "calcular" ese id en funcion del año y de la fecha, no? si es asi, no veo necesario que lo guardes

Comment: @Jakala Indico que lo guardo por el tema que no quiero perder los registros del año anterior , y que pueda simplemente visualizarlos , pero me dio otra perspectiva , Muchas Gracias! , Abusando de su amabilidad , sabe como se puede enviar una variable de forma automatica a otra vista si se cumple una condicion if?